# Secure Boot driver signature fails after disk conversion to UEFI - Windows Server 2019

Tags: windows-server-2019, uefi, secure-boot

I have a number of servers I need to get converted to UEFI from MBR disk.  I have the process for this working well in a lab environment but when I try to do it on production servers after the computer has been converted to UEFI, the BIOS reconfigured, Windows refuses to boot due to driver signature errors on the hard drive driver.

I have performed DISM /cleanup-image /Restorehealth and SFC /scannow to ensure all drivers and other components are current and health before doing the conversion using the command MBR2GPT /convert /AllowFullOS.

After the conversion to UEFI I have booted to WinPE, manually added drivers using PNPUTIL so I can see the OS drive.  Then I run BCDBOOT C:\Windows /s  H: /f UEFI  to rebuild the boot records.  Upon booting I get the driver signature warning.  Even doing the option to not validate signatures does not work.  I have to disable Secure Boot in BIOS to get the system to boot.

My main question is how can I correct the driver signature issue either by updating the known/trusted drivers or completely wiping the driver database and get a fresh start.  I am basically looking for anything that will get me past these driver signature issues and still have Secure Boot enabled.

Comment: What driver(s)? What vendor(s)?

Comment: In this case specifically Scale Computing Guest Tools drivers for the hard drive viostor.inf. For those not familiar with Scale Computing, it is like VMware Tools drivers.   I believe this issue can be answered in general as far as how to rebuild the trusted set of drivers/signatures as I am sure there is nothing specific int he drivers that cause this. They were previously trusted before doing a conversion of the drive from MBR to GPT.

Comment: Do they say they support UEFI? This document says that they do not support UEFI: https://www.scalecomputing.com/documents/Data-Sheets/support_matrix_hc3_software.pdf

Comment: Nice catch Greg but in this case they do support it.  The document you linked shows for versions 7.x and 8.x but we are on 9.2 which explicitly adds UEFI+vTPM functionality.  Also, I have worked directly with their support and engineering teams  on the project I am working on that leads up to this to work through the issues that have come up (We are lucky to have be partners and have close contact with Scale support) however at this point we are beyond compatibility with the hypervisor and it is at the OS level now.

Comment: Looks like the internet has no good solution for this or has not run across it.  I have since opened a ticket with Microsoft and will post any solution from that if they provide one.  ticket opened Sept 20th but still no call or email from them.  Maybe I stumped everyone :)